# Вычислить сумму четных положительных элементов

Tags: windows

Как вычислить сумму четных положительных элементов?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo off
chcp 65001
set /p n=Введите количество чётных положительных элементов: 
set res=0
echo Введите чётные положительные элементы по одному на строке
for /l %%q in (1, 1, %n%) do set /p x= && set /a res=res+x
echo Вычисленная сумма: %res%
pause
```

Comment: Ему нужны чётные, а не просто целые... поправь, а то вдруг не справится...

Comment: это на каком языке?)

Comment: очевидно, на языке "windows"

Comment: @Akina, поправил))

Comment: @michael_best, это bat'ник)) У вопроса же тег windows :D